# Virtual and real in the case of hologram images?

Tags: optics, hologram

Are the terms virtual and real applicable to hologram images? Is the hologram image *real* if the observer sees it in front of the photographic plate, so he could 'touch' it, and *virtual* if the observer sees it behind the plate?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the answer is "yes".  From [http://web.pa.msu.edu/courses/2000fall/PHY232/lectures/lenses/images.html], "Real images are those where light actually converges, whereas virtual images are locations from where light appears to have converged."

Comment: Can you perhaps include a reference?

Comment: Sure: [https://web.pa.msu.edu/courses/2000fall/PHY232/lectures/lenses/images.html]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please edit that into the answer itself? Comments are sometimes deleted. Cheers!